# Как сделать такие разрывы в border?

Tags: css

С помощью псевдоэлэментов, градиента или же другие методы? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно за счет белой окантовки вокруг кнопки, которая закроет собой бордер.. или уже svg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как уже написал [@Stranger in the Q](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059595/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-border#comment1812941_1059595), вам нужна окантовка дочернего элемента, который будет перекрывать border родителя.
Окантовку проще всего сделать при помощи [`box-shadow`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow).

Цвет фона элемента и цвет `box-shadow` должны быть того же цвета что и фон, в вашем случае - белым цветом.

```css
.border {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.icon {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -25px auto 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff;
}

#change:checked ~ .border > .icon {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
<input id="change" type="checkbox"> <label for="change">Сменить цвет box-shadow</label>

<div class="border">
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

Если же нужно провернуть такую процедуру с более сложным фоном, например картинкой, то придётся обратиться за помощью к SVG.

Answer (score 4):

Вот ещё как вариант. Только больно объемно получается.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.body:before,
.body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.body:before {
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.body:after {
  right: 0;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.box__top {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.box__top {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box__top:before,
.box__top:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box__top:before {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -45px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.box__top:after {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -45px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.top {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}

.top__icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 70px;
}

.top__icon:after {
  content: 'иконка';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.box__bottom {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.box__bottom {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box__bottom:before,
.box__bottom:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}

.box__bottom:before {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.box__bottom:after {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.bottom {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}

.bottom__icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="top__icon"></div>
  <div class="box__top">
    <div class="top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box__bottom">
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom__icon">Рассчитать</div>
</div>
```