# Убрать часть Bordera у блока

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убрать border возле иконки и кнопки, как лучше сделать? Может кому-то приходилось делать

```
 .consultation{
    padding: 55px 0 80px 0;
    &__title{
        color: #3a3a3a;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
    }
    &__form{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #898989;
        padding: 68px 0 53px 0;
        button{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -25px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
        input{
            padding: 15px 30px;
            border: 1px solid #898989;
            border-radius: 30px;
            margin: 0 2.5px;
            width: 270px;
        }
    }
    &__agent{
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #e93b3b;
        border-radius: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        top: -50px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
}



   <form action="#" class="consultation__form">
                            <img src="./img/icons/agentRed.png" alt="agent" class="consultation__agent">
                            <input type="text" name="UserName" placeholder="Ваше имя...">
                            <input type="tel" name="UserPhone" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона...">
                            <input type="email" name="UserEmail" placeholder="Ваш e-mail...">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn_f">Отправить заявку</button>

                        </form>
```

Comment: бордер где? у инпута? или эти 2 серые полоски?

Comment: Хм, написал свой ответ первым, а его удалили и указали, что я сдублировал ответ, который типо уже был. Притом ответить на удаление я не могу. Интересненько.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, если суть в пространствах слева и справа от аватарки,то попробуйте как то так:

```
.consultation__agent{
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Уже решил,спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если эти 2 серые полоски то соответственно

```
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
```

А так глянуть бы на код, и на то чего хотите добиться, а то не совсем понятно

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите(HTML,SCSS)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте элементам `box-shadow` с цветом родительского фона.

Аналогичный вопрос и подробный ответ к нему находится тут - [Как сделать такие разрывы в border?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1059595/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-border/1059598#1059598)